# Jest testing with mockRejectedValueOnce does not find error message

Tags: reactjs, typescript, testing, jestjs

I'm having a problem when testing a React component with Jest and React Testing Library. I have a LoginPage component where I'm testing various cases.

I'm using react-query for handling server requests and mutations. The mutation to sign in looks like this:

```js
const signInMutation = useMutation(
  (credentials: Credential) => auth.signIn(credentials),
  {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      setShowAlert(true);
      setAlerSeverenity('success');
      setAlertMessage(data.message);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setShowAlert(false);
        navigate('/dashboard');
      }, 1500);
    },
    onError: (error: any) => {
      setShowAlert(true);
      setAlerSeverenity('error');
      setAlertMessage(error?.response?.data?.message || 'Unknown Error');
      setTimeout(() => {
        setShowAlert(false);
      }, 1500);
    },
  },
);
```

The signIn function in AuthService looks like this:

```js
async signIn({ username, password }: { username: string; password: string }) {
  try {
    const data = { username: username, password: password };
    const response = await this.instance.post('signin', data, {
      withCredentials: true,
    });

    sessionStorage.setItem('username', response.data.data.username);
    sessionStorage.setItem('role', response.data.data.role);
    sessionStorage.setItem('token', response.data.data.access_token);

    return response.data;
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw error.response.data;
  }
}
```

In my Jest tests, I'm mocking the AuthService.signIn method and testing the behavior of the component when the promise is resolved and when it's rejected.

My test setup looks like this:

```js
import { screen, render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from 'react-query';
import LoginPage from '../LoginPage';
import AuthService from '../../../../service/AuthService/AuthService';

describe('Submit Form with Valid Input', () => {
  it('Submit form with valid Credentials', async () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(AuthService.prototype, 'signIn')
      .mockResolvedValueOnce({ message: 'Sign in data authenticated' });

    const queryClient = new QueryClient();
    render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <LoginPage />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );

    const usernameInput = screen.getByLabelText('Please Input Username');
    const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText('Please Input Password');
    const loginButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Login' });

    fireEvent.change(usernameInput, { target: { value: 'validUser' } });
    fireEvent.change(passwordInput, { target: { value: 'validPassword' } });
    fireEvent.click(loginButton);

    const successMessage = await screen.findByText(
      'Sign in data authenticated',
    );
    expect(successMessage).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  it('Submit form with Invalid Credentials', async () => {
    jest
      .spyOn(AuthService.prototype, 'signIn')
      .mockRejectedValueOnce({ message: 'Unknown Error' });

    const queryClient = new QueryClient();

    render(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
          <LoginPage />
        </QueryClientProvider>
      </MemoryRouter>,
    );

    const usernameInput = screen.getByLabelText('Please Input Username');
    const passwordInput = screen.getByLabelText('Please Input Password');
    const loginButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Login' });

    fireEvent.change(usernameInput, {
      target: { value: 'invalidUser' },
    });
    fireEvent.change(passwordInput, {
      target: { value: 'invalidPassword' },
    });
    fireEvent.click(loginButton);

    const errorMessage = await screen.findByText('Unknown Error');
    expect(errorMessage).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

The test case with mockResolvedValueOnce works as expected. However, when testing the case with mockRejectedValueOnce, the error message cannot be found, and my test fails. i expect the last test case when input invalid credential error can find the error text on error message render. so the test would coverage by 100%

Does anyone have any idea why the test with mockRejectedValueOnce fails to find the error message?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).